# Update column in table to two concatenated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 3 columns in a table 
`paxname` `fname` `lname`
now i want to concatenate `fname` and `lname` 
and update that in paxname

My following query did not work

```
update pax set paxname =lname || " " || fname
```

I tried with CONCAT function but it didnt work either.

Comment: CONCAT Should have worked - show the code you used with CONCAT (you were possibly just using it wrong).

Comment: @ZoharPeled...am using Sql server 2005...

Comment: am writing this query...update pax set paxname=concat(fname,"",lname)

Comment: SQL Server has `+` for concatenation.

Comment: while putting + am getting this error...Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The "truncated" error is probably because the total characters in fname + lname + 1 (for the space) exceeds the maximum length of paxname.

Answer (score 3):

Use following command:

```
UPDATE pax SET paxname = lname + ' ' + fname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update pax set paxname=lname + " " + fname
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `||` is concatenation operator in `Oracle` and it does not work in `T-SQL`.

Your update can be written to also compensate for `NULL` values, as + operator will nullify the result, if any of the operands is `NULL`.

```
update pax set paxname = isnull(lname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(fname, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can try like this:

```
UPDATE pax 
SET paxname = CONCAT_WS(' ', lname , fname)
```

In SQL Server it will be

```
UPDATE pax 
SET paxname  =lname + ' ' + fname
```

Comment: it is showing me this error...Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '|'.

Comment: @user3305327:- try to use this SQL `UPDATE pax 
SET paxname  =lname + ' ' + fname`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT like this:

```
update pax set paxname=concat(lname ,' ',fname)
```